# Incluir um arquivo externo ao CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, moodle

Estou tentando fazer uma integração entre um sistema desenvolvido em CodeIgniter(CI) com o Moodle e preciso incluir no CI um arquivo da biblioteca do Moodle, para recuperar alguns dados.

No entanto não estou conseguindo fazer a inclusao do arquvio no CI, para trabalhar com ele dentro dos controllers. A inclusao do arquivo funciona perfeitamente no index.php do CI, mas não consigo usar as suas variaveis dentro dos controllers

Lembrando que meu CI esta dentro de uma pasta do Moodle, ou seja seria um modulo deste sistema.

Alguem tem conhecimentos para realizar esta integração?

A estrutura esta assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quero incluir dentro do CI o arquivo parametros.php e usar suas variaveis nos controllers

Arquivo parametros.php

```
<?php   
    unset($CFG);
    global $CFG;
    $CFG = new stdClass();
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/setup.php');
```

O lib/setup.php pode ser visualizado aqui:

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/setup.php

Comment: Você instanciou ela onde? Já tentou ver no load.php, pra dar um load automatico no model?

Comment: Não é um model, o Moodle é um CMS

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do arquivo?

Comment: É uma variavel que contem um objeto

Comment: Posta o conteudo, existe inumeras maneiras de criar as variaveis, pode ser em array, pode ser em qualquer coisa. A sessão só falha com o arquivo incluido ou falha sem?

Comment: Cara, esse arquivo é como se fosse um autoload do Moodle, ele importa varias classes pra dentro desse arquivo, e desses arquivos tem outros varios carregamentos. O que impossibilita de colocar todos os arquivos aqui, mas basicamente o parametros.php é o que coloquei agora na descricao.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa inserir o Moodle na pasta "application/third_party", após isso na "libraries" inserir um arquivo "Moddle.php"

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/moodle/index.php';

class CIMoodle extends Moodle {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // Outros métodos aqui.
}
```

Após isso no controller só usar um

```
$this->load->library("cimoodle");
$todo = $this->cimoodle->algummetodo();
```

Comment: Eu não posso fazer desta forma, pois o Moodle é o sistema principal, o Codeigniter seria um modulo para ele, com uma aplicação antiga. 

No caso basicamente preciso pegar a sessão do Moodle e utilizar ela no Codeigniter, por isso to tentando incluir o arquivo com as sessoes do Moodle

Comment: Desculpe então, eu tinha entendido errado.

Comment: Penso que você ainda pode fazer algo parecido, ignore o "third_party" e instancie no construct de uma lib a sessão do moodle, depois só ir recuperando os dados dentro dos métodos da lib.

Comment: Vou tentar dessa forma vinicius, e seguir por este caminho. Vamos ver onde vou chegar... Obrigado

Comment: Até esse ponto deu certo, o problema e que se inicializo a sessão do codeigniter ele encerra a sessao ativa do Moodle.

Comment: tente capturar a seção do moodle em vez de substitui-la no codeigniter, atribua a nova sessão dentro dela.

Comment: mas é exatamente isso que to querendo fazer, mas ainda nao descobri como, pois pra recuperar a sessão eu preciso fazer esse include

Comment: Não obrigatoriamente precisa fazer um include, sessões não são armazenadas pelo sistema e sim pelo servidor, então em qualquer diretório do sv você consegue acessar uma sessão do sistema X ou Y.